# What does first argument as a path to a filename mean?

Tags: c++, file, command-line-arguments, filenames

I was poking around codeeval.com which is a site you use to look at coding challenges, and I noticed quite a few of them have the following specification:

```
Your program should accept as its first argument a path to a filename
```

An example would be as follows:

Description:

Write a program to determine the Mth to last element of a list.

Input sample:

The first argument will be a text file containing a series of space delimited characters followed by an integer representing a index into the list(1 based), one per line. e.g. 
... (the question goes on to explain what the input is).

Would this mean that when I compile my program, I would use argv[0] as the parameter to accept the file? An example is shown below. I'm just a bit confused on what the prompt is asking. Thanks for your help!

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ifstream file;
   file.open(argv[0]);
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argv[0]` typically refers to the name of the program being executed. You would use `argv[1]` (which is the first argument to your program other than the name of the program).

Make sure `argc >= 2` before attempting to dereference `argv[1]`.

See http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html for more details about how to use `argc` and `argv` to receive command-line arguments.